Does CopyOnWriteArrayList can result inRace Condition when modified by 2 or more Threads in Parallel
I was trying to do some experminet with CopyOnWriteArrayList and found that when 2 threads are concurrently modifying same CopyOnWriteArrayList object, the final result changes in different run.
Sample code:
package practice.javaconcepts;

import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class CowalExample{

    static CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> cowal = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        cowal.add(1);
        cowal.add(2);
        cowal.add(3);
        cowal.add(4);

        Thread thread1= new Thread1(cowal);
        Thread thread2= new Thread2(cowal);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Nothing");
        }
        for(int i: cowal)
        {
            System.out.println("Number is : "+i);
        }
    }
}

class Thread1 extends Thread
{
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> cowal;

    Thread1(CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> cowal)
    {
        this.cowal=cowal;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        int k=0;
        for(int i: cowal)
        {
            cowal.set(k,cowal.get(k)+1);
            k++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Thread2 extends Thread
{
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> cowal;

    Thread2(CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> cowal)
    {
        this.cowal=cowal;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        int k=0;
        for(int i: cowal)
        {
            cowal.set(k,cowal.get(k)+1);
            k++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

Attaching 2 different outputs I got in 2 different program runs.

My question is: Isn't CopyOnWriteArrayList supposed to be ThreadSafe without this race condition?

"... when 2 threads are concurrently modifying same CopyOnWriteArrayList object, the final result changes in different run." - Yes, this is expected behavior for multithreading. And not, this is NOT a race condition. Thread safety of the collection guarantees that non-synchronized, concurrent usage of its methods won't break the collection itself. In some sense, thread safety means that every collection's method is "atomic". But calling several methods, like you do in cowal.set(k,cowal.get(k)+1);, is no longer atomic.

Consider possible sequences of methods calling in different threads for a single value of k=0: Sequence 1. Thread1 performs cowal.get(1) and gets 1; thread1 performs cowal.set(k, 1 + 1) which stores 2; thread2 performs cowal.get(1) and gets 2; thread2 performs cowal.set(k, 2 + 1) which stores 3. Sequence 2. Thread1 performs cowal.get(1) and gets 1; thread2 performs cowal.get(1) and gets 1; thread1 performs cowal.set(k, 1 + 1) which stores 2; thread1 performs cowal.set(k, 1 + 1) which stores 2.

Then how does it differ from normal ArrayList. Won't we get the same behavior in that case also?

Yes, you would observe the same behavior when use common ArrayList with adding a lock around every its method invocation. Aside from thread-safety, CopyOnWriteArrayList differs from ArrayList only in time costs: modification methods takes more time, but copying arrays is much cheaper. You could find more details about that difference in the Java documentation.

You could use Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()) to get a thread safe collection with ArrayList characteristics. The behavior would be the same as with the question’s code, as the problem is the application logic. That’s why you rarely need a “thread safe collection” in practice but a thread safe application design. In most cases, when the application uses the right guards for the application level operations, the thread safety for the underlying data structures comes for free.
